# Не работает родительский hover при наведении на дочерний svg

Tags: javascript, css, jquery, svg

Всем привет, ребята. Почему при наведении на svg не показывается tooltip, он же в div находиться. В чем причина, как думаете? Есть решение данной проблемы?

[Код на Codepen (https://codepen.io/kekoklol/pen/qBVZXQK)](https://codepen.io/kekoklol/pen/qBVZXQK)

```js
let tooltipElem;
document.onmouseover = function(event) {
  let target = event.target;

  // если у нас есть подсказка...
  let tooltipHtml = target.dataset.tooltip;
  if (!tooltipHtml) return;

  // ...создадим элемент для подсказки
  tooltipElem = document.createElement('div');
  tooltipElem.className = 'tooltip';
  tooltipElem.innerHTML = tooltipHtml;
  document.body.append(tooltipElem);

  // спозиционируем его сверху от аннотируемого элемента (top-center)
  let coords = target.getBoundingClientRect();

  let left = coords.left + (target.offsetWidth - tooltipElem.offsetWidth) / 2;
  if (left < 0) left = 0; // не заезжать за левый край окна

  let top = coords.top - tooltipElem.offsetHeight - 5;
  if (top < 0) { // если подсказка не помещается сверху, то отображать её снизу
    top = coords.top + target.offsetHeight + 5;
  }

  tooltipElem.style.left = left + 'px';
  tooltipElem.style.top = top + 'px';
  tooltipElem.style.transform = 'none';
};

document.onmouseout = function(e) {

  if (tooltipElem) {
    tooltipElem.remove();
    tooltipElem = null;
  }

};
```

```css
svg {
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div data-tooltip="Данный пользователь обожает котиков">Пользователь 2145
  <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="user-check" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 640 512" class="svg-inline--fa fa-user-check fa-w-20 fa-2x"><path fill="currentColor" d="M224 256c70.7 0 128-57.3 128-128S294.7 0 224 0 96 57.3 96 128s57.3 128 128 128zm89.6 32h-16.7c-22.2 10.2-46.9 16-72.9 16s-50.6-5.8-72.9-16h-16.7C60.2 288 0 348.2 0 422.4V464c0 26.5 21.5 48 48 48h352c26.5 0 48-21.5 48-48v-41.6c0-74.2-60.2-134.4-134.4-134.4zm323-128.4l-27.8-28.1c-4.6-4.7-12.1-4.7-16.8-.1l-104.8 104-45.5-45.8c-4.6-4.7-12.1-4.7-16.8-.1l-28.1 27.9c-4.7 4.6-4.7 12.1-.1 16.8l81.7 82.3c4.6 4.7 12.1 4.7 16.8.1l141.3-140.2c4.6-4.7 4.7-12.2.1-16.8z" class=""></path></svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Вы проверяете наличие `tooltip` непосредственно у элемента, на который наводите (`let tooltipHtml = target.dataset.tooltip;`), но у вашего SVG `tooltip` отсутствует, поэтому и не выводит.

Comment: @Pilaton, спасибо, что направили на решение проблемы, я это ценю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подсказка добавляется при "наезде" на элемент содержащему *data-tooltip*.
Так как обработчики событий отлавливают *onmouseover* и *onmouseout* на всех элементах, то при попадании на SVG, у которого нет атрибута *data-tooltip*, подсказка исчезает.

Простейшее решение - сделать SVG "прозрачным" для действий мыши, с помощью `pointer-events: none` :

```js
let tooltipElem;
document.onmouseover = function(event) {
  let target = event.target;

  // если у нас есть подсказка...
  let tooltipHtml = target.dataset.tooltip;
  if (!tooltipHtml) return;

  // ...создадим элемент для подсказки
  tooltipElem = document.createElement('div');
  tooltipElem.className = 'tooltip';
  tooltipElem.innerHTML = tooltipHtml;
  document.body.append(tooltipElem);

  // спозиционируем его сверху от аннотируемого элемента (top-center)
  let coords = target.getBoundingClientRect();

  let left = coords.left + (target.offsetWidth - tooltipElem.offsetWidth) / 2;
  if (left < 0) left = 0; // не заезжать за левый край окна

  let top = coords.top - tooltipElem.offsetHeight - 5;
  if (top < 0) { // если подсказка не помещается сверху, то отображать её снизу
    top = coords.top + target.offsetHeight + 5;
  }

  tooltipElem.style.left = left + 'px';
  tooltipElem.style.top = top + 'px';
  tooltipElem.style.transform = 'none';
};

document.onmouseout = function(e) {

  if (tooltipElem) {
    tooltipElem.remove();
    tooltipElem = null;
  }

};
```

```css
svg {
  width: 20px;
}

div[data-tooltip] * {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div data-tooltip="Данный пользователь обожает котиков">Пользователь 2145
  <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="user-check" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 640 512" class="svg-inline--fa fa-user-check fa-w-20 fa-2x">
    <path fill="currentColor" d="M224 256c70.7 0 128-57.3 128-128S294.7 0 224 0 96 57.3 96 128s57.3 128 128 128zm89.6 32h-16.7c-22.2 10.2-46.9 16-72.9 16s-50.6-5.8-72.9-16h-16.7C60.2 288 0 348.2 0 422.4V464c0 26.5 21.5 48 48 48h352c26.5 0 48-21.5 48-48v-41.6c0-74.2-60.2-134.4-134.4-134.4zm323-128.4l-27.8-28.1c-4.6-4.7-12.1-4.7-16.8-.1l-104.8 104-45.5-45.8c-4.6-4.7-12.1-4.7-16.8-.1l-28.1 27.9c-4.7 4.6-4.7 12.1-.1 16.8l81.7 82.3c4.6 4.7 12.1 4.7 16.8.1l141.3-140.2c4.6-4.7 4.7-12.2.1-16.8z" class=""></path>
  </svg>
  <span>Текст</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Вместе с Вашим обновленным кодом не знаете, как решить проблему, если конструкция такова: <div data-tooltip="текст"><svg>...</svg><span>Текст</span>. В этой конструкции когда курсор наводишь на span то подсказка пропадает. Пробовал делать проверку, есть ли у родительского элемента дата атрибут, и если есть то выводить подсказку. Но ничего не получалось.. Спасибо большое за подсказку, Вы огромный молодец.

Comment: а что предпринять, если вместо div тэг a? С <a> работает только на тексте "Пользователь 2145".

Comment: @ОливерЛинкольн: добавьте для ссылки `display: block;` или `display: inline-block;`